# Blank page with no error output on production artisan config:cache

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, laravel-artisan

I have a laravel project, which when I deploy to my production site works fine as long as I don't call `php artisan config:cache` during the build process.

Strangely, my app still shows the login page, but once I have logged in, every page is blank and there is no output in any logs.

**I have tried**

My `bootstrap/cache` folder is of 777 permissions as is the `storage/` folder. Which are the most recommended fixes to this in other posts I have searched.

Run my build file adding commands one by one until the issue reproduces itself and have deduced that it was `config:cache` causing the issue.

Checking php-fpm logs
Checking laravel logs
Checking nginx logs

I'm using laravel 5.8, but this issue was also present in 5.7.

**Composer deps**

```
"davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "5.x",
"doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
"fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
"fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
"igaster/laravel-theme": "^2.0",
"intervention/image": "^2.4",
"laravel/cashier": "~9.0",
"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
"laravel/passport": "^7.0",
"laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
"league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "~1.0",
"owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^9.0",
"setasign/fpdi-fpdf": "^2.0",
"setasign/fpdi-tcpdf": "^2.0",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.12",
"spatie/laravel-sluggable": "^2.1"
```

**Build commands**

```
chmod -R 0777 storage/
composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-interaction
php artisan migrate
php artisan route:cache
php artisan storage:link
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: What's service you using? (Apache or nginx). Please check their logs

Comment: Check logs everywhere. I had this problem on my development environment and the errors was in my php-fpm logs.

Comment: Nothing in nginx logs
Nothing in php-fpm logs

Comment: Nothing in `storage/logs/laravel.log` either? Is your `storage/logs` folder writable? And the log file(s) within? Try to set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file and see if `php artisan config:clear` does anything.

Comment: @AdamCopley : Can you share build commands which you are using with sequence.

Comment: Added build commands and have checked permissions on logs folders

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to access index.php?

debug sequentially follow Laravel life-cycle:

1. index.php
2. bootstrap app.php
3. Http/Kernel.php
4. Appserviceproviders